# Sqoop Import with multiple Primary keys

Tags: sqoop

How to create a sqoop job to import data from MySql with composite primary key? how to pass 2 or 3 PK in `--check-column`? As of now it is throwing error for passing more than 1 key.

Comment: please format your question

Comment: For help with this, read How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: sqoop command : sqoop job --create <sqpjob> -- import --connect <connection_string> --username=uname --password=password --table <sqltable> --incremental append --check-column col1,col2,col3 --hive-import --hive-table dbname.tablename --as-textfile;


in sqltable columns are like :col1 primary key,col2 primary key,col3 primary key,col4,col5,col6

while executing sqoop job :- sqoop job --exec sqpjob

it is throwing error:ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: java.io.IOException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'col1,col2,col3' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

If your table has no index column, or has a multi-column key, then you must  manually choose a splitting column in `--split-by` parameter to import data.

You can't pass more than 1 column names in `--check-column` parameter. It specifies the column to be examined when determining which rows to import.

Comment: Hi Iskuskov..For --split-by i don't have a single column with unique values.I have combination of 3 columns as a unique key..that case in split-by also we can't pass more than one column..

Comment: It can be solved on database level: can you introduce surrogate single-column primary key?

Comment: Is there column represents timestamp value of table update?

Comment: no..no column with timestamps value.otherwise would have gone with split-by tamestamp col..